# change file name with mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

If you have a file `/foo/index.html` that you want to access via `/bar/index.html` that's easy enough with a rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$    foo/$1 [L] # <-- Leaves URL the same, but gives content of foo/
```

But that means both `/foo/index.html` and `/bar/index.html` now work to access the content. Is there a way to now disallow access via `/foo/index.html`? Just doing:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$    bar/$1 [R=301,L] # <-- Change the URL if accessed via /foo
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$    foo/$1 [L] # <-- Leaves URL the same, but gives content of foo/
```

causes a redirect loop. Is there a way to indicate "redirect foo to bar, unless the URL is already '/bar'"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, but you need to do a check against something like `%{THE_REQUEST}` otherwise your two rules are going to keep changing each other's rewrites and loop. So something like:

```
# this is the rule you already had:
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$    foo/$1 [L]

# this is the rule that externally redirects
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /foo/
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /bar/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The check against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable ensures that the *actual request* was made for `/foo`, and not an internally rewritten request.

Comment: Bravo! I was trying to mess with `%{REQUEST_URI}` to get this to work, with no luck; `%{THE_REQUEST}` works as expected!